# org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! python: can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, apache-storm, flux

Whenever I try to run my storm topology locally I get the following

error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
python: can't open file 'parser_bolt.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I have searched everywhere on the internet but not able to resolve this issue. I can see the respective python file in the resources folder when I unzip the compiled jar but somehow when deploying the jar its unable to find the python files from the topology.

Comment: I even tried the example from the wordcount and even there I got the error: python: can't open file 'splitbolt.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same error with a Python bolt that I created.  My issue was I forgot to call run on the class at the bottom of the Python code.  Example code below.

```
import storm

class TestStuff(storm.BasicBolt)

     def initialize(self,conf,context):
          self._conf = conf;
          self._context = context;

     def process(self, tuple):
          storm.logInfo("test")

TestStuff().run()
```

The last line of the sample code is what I forgot to put in, thus causing the error.  Make sure you have that.